# iOS - Need Date Picker like this

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

Please check image below. I need to create date picker like this in green box.

I have two questions regarding this.

1. Is it possible to create below date picker using UIDatePicker?  I have tried all datePickerMode. There is no option like this.
2. Is there any third party framework for this?

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a UIPickerView (Which is different than a UIDatePicker) with only 1 component. You would provide the data for every row in that component as the Month/Day. A UIDatePicker is very basically a UIPickerView that always populates with dates and/or times.

If you're looking for a 3rd party library you can take a look at [Awesome iOS](https://github.com/vsouza/awesome-ios) and see if there's something there that's what you're looking for.